# Facebook Messenger Chess

Tags: online-chess

Have anyone here experimented the Chess of Facebook Messenger?
I've heard about this and would like to get the comands/ codes to play.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GM Smerdon [has written a blogpost](http://www.davidsmerdon.com/?p=1804) about this.

Some of the commands:

```
@fbchess play  (or @fbchess play white)
@fbchess help  (will give you a list of commands)
```

Case sensitive algebraic notation:

```
@fbchess Bg7
@fbchess e4

@fbchess undo
@fbchess resign
```